# Convert a given binary string into Integer and Vice Versa in Java

Tags: java, type-conversion

I'm trying to convert a binary number in string into integer and vice versa . For eg -

Binary = 001
Integer - 1
I know i can do this like

```
int decimal = 0;  
int n = 0;  
while(true){  
  if(binary == 0){  
    break;  
  } else {  
      int temp = binary%10;  
      decimal += temp*Math.pow(2, n);  
      binary = binary/10;  
      n++;  
   }  
}  
return decimal;
```

I want conversions between these two using some direct functions. Can anyone please help me. Thankyou.

Comment: Use what's already available: `Integer.parseInt("1101", 2)` and `Integer.toString(13, 2)`.

Answer (score 0):

So here is a simple answer for this. To Convert a Binary String let us say eg S= "001" to Integer use - `Integer.parse(S,2)` and to convert a Integer back to Binary String use- `Integer.toBinaryString(num)`

Hope This Helps. Thankyou.